# ASP.NET MVC Url.RouteUrl for Default Route in Area using "Details" as Action parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Agents - Default",
    "agent/{username}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Agent", action = "Profile" }
);
```

If i do this in my code:

```
var url = helper.RouteUrl("Agents - Default", new { username })
```

It generates a URL like this:

> "/agent/joebloggs/Details"

Whereas i would expect it to generate a URL like this:

> "/agent/joebloggs"

(which resolves/matches the route fine when i hit manually)

If i change it to this:

```
var url = helper.RouteUrl("Agents - Default", new { username }, action = "Profile" })
```

It works fine, but i thought the point of the route default is that i don't *need* to do that.

Any ideas? Where it is pulling this "Details" part from?

Comment: are you on the current `Details` route?

Comment: @DanielA.White no, i am on a completely different page/area. What's interesting is if im on that page (`/agent/joebloggs`), the same `RouteUrl` works fine

Comment: @DanielA.White interestingly though, i *am* on a page whose actionname is "Details".. is it inheriting it instead of using the default for the new route?

Comment: That's why. You could always specify the route name

Comment: @DanielA.White i don't understand what you mean, i *am* specifying the route name? (first param)

Answer (score 2):

The `RouteUrl` must have enough information to match the route. Route name is just another narrowing specification for the match.

But the main issue you have is that you are not declaring the route values as name-value pairs, so MVC won't be able to convert it to a `RouteValueDictionary`.

```
var url = helper.RouteUrl("Agents - Default", new { username = "MyUser" })
```

**Update**

> i am on a page whose actionname is "Details"

This is your main issue. The default behavior of MVC is to always use any keys that are not set from the current context when generating outgoing URLs. So for example, if your current action is "Details" and you don't set an action when generating your URL, then it will ***automatically*** inject a route value `action = "Details"`. Some people consider this "feature" of MVC to be a bug. See [work item 1346](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1346).

Aside from the solutions that are provided by Microsoft in the above link, another workaround is to create a fake request context to eliminate these extra values, which might be cleaner in your case.

```
var currentHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;

// Get the route data for the current route
// using the current HTTP context.
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(currentHttpContext));

// Create a URI based on the home page to ensure no query string
// parameters are injected into the URL.
var uri = new Uri(currentHttpContext.Request.Url, "/");

// Create an HTTP request based on the URI
var request = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, uri.ToString(), uri.Query);

// Create a TextWriter with null stream as a backing stream 
// which doesn't consume resources
using (var nullWriter = new StreamWriter(Stream.Null))
{
    // Create an HTTP response based on a null writer.
    var response = new HttpResponse(nullWriter);

    // Create a fake HTTP context
    var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(request, response));

    // Create a fake RequestContext
    var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);

    // Use the fake RequestContext to generate the URL without
    // unexpectedly injecting the action name of the current request.
    var helper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
    var url = helper.RouteUrl("Agents - Default", new { username = "MyUser" });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your answer. If the value of `username` is "MyUser", then `new { username }` is the same as `new { username = "MyUser" }`...right? (in C# anonymous types speak anyway). The answer you have provided doesn't solve the issue... i think what @Daniel A. White alluded to is the issue.

Comment: No, that is not correct. A dictionary is a set of keys and values, the way you have it configured is for a simple collection (with a value only).